# Nvidia-settings libharfbuzz.so.0 error

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia

Every time Issue the command `nvidia-settings -I /usr/lib/libnvidia-gtk3.so.381.22` I get the following error:

```
ERROR: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0: undefined symbol:
       FT_Reference_Face


ERROR: A problem occured when loading the GUI library. Please check your
       installation and library path. You may need to specify this library when
       calling nvidia-settings. Please run `nvidia-settings --help` for usage
       information.
```

I have to point directly to the GTK lib because the package wants to look for a different one that does not exist.

This happened after I upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: A simple online search leads me to believe that `FT_Reference_Face` is part of `FreeType`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand that it is and have searched as well. Would getting rid of libfreetype6 help? Don't a lot of other packages depend on freetype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by going here [LINK](http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/freetype/)

I then found the file named 'freetype-2.8.tar.gz' extracted it, and then I ran the command `./configure` in that directory, and then ran `make` I received an error and had to modify the file to what the error suggests. You will see this when you ran the command. After correcting everything I ran the command `sudo make install`

After doing all of the above, nvidia-settings finally worked.